# Getting low, high, and mean from column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the low, high and mean from a column. However, I'd like to only aggregate by the column value. For example, if we have 2 rows with the same column value, then we aggregate these two together. Also, they have to be of the same carrier. Something like this:

Before processing:

```
carrier   class   price
SP        A       22
VZ        C       33
XM        A       50 
XM        D       20     
SP        A       88
VZ        C       100
```

After processing:

```
carrier   class   price   low   high   mean
SP        A       22      22    88     55
VZ        C       33      33    100    66.5
XM        A       50      50    50     50
XM        D       20      20    20     20
SP        A       88      22    88     55
VZ        C       100     33    100    66.5
```

As you can see, if we have the same carrier and same class, then we aggregate and get the low, high, and mean. If we have the same carrier, but no same class then we don't aggregate, but we still get the low, high, mean which is the same number as the class' price.

I want the result to be exactly as the way it is after processing. The result should be a dataframe. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What have your tried? Anything with `groupby`?

Comment: `df.groupby('carrier').price.agg(['min','max','mean'])
` ?

Comment: example should be `df.groupby('A').agg('min')` similarly `max` or `mean` you can use if you are looking  for this.

Comment: @ALollz I actually made a typo so I edited the question again. Since `XM` have 2 different classes, then we do not aggregate those 2 classes together. So they should have separate low, high and mean just like how I have it in the after processing table.

Comment: @ALollz Very sorry about that, another typo. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with list of tuples foe new columns names with aggregate function and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame`:

```
d = [('low','min'),('high','max'),('mean','mean')]
df1 = df.join(df.groupby(['carrier','class'])['price'].agg(d), on=['carrier','class'])
print (df1)
  carrier class  price  low  high  mean
0      SP     A     22   22    88  55.0
1      VZ     C     33   33   100  66.5
2      XM     A     50   50    50  50.0
3      XM     D     20   20    20  20.0
4      SP     A     88   22    88  55.0
5      VZ     C    100   33   100  66.5
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby(['carrier','class'])['price'].agg(d))
               low  high  mean
carrier class                 
SP      A       22    88  55.0
VZ      C       33   100  66.5
XM      A       50    50  50.0
        D       20    20  20.0
```

Or use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), fun solution:

```
d = [('low','min'),('high','max'),('mean','mean')]
g = df.groupby(['carrier','class'])['price']
for i, j in d:
    df[i] = g.transform(j)
print (df)
  carrier class  price  low  high  mean
0      SP     A     22   22    88  55.0
1      VZ     C     33   33   100  66.5
2      XM     A     50   50    50  50.0
3      XM     D     20   20    20  20.0
4      SP     A     88   22    88  55.0
5      VZ     C    100   33   100  66.5
```

Comment: @ALollz - Just test it and different output.

Comment: @ALollz - it looks like some rows are missing in input sample data.

Comment: @jezrael Sorry, I made some typos in the same data. Just fixed it now.